# Page Region not display full page width

Tags: oracle-apex

This is an odd one to me because it only started happening since we moved to Apex 4.2. To get round the problem i have to copy and paste regions I already have in the application, rather than simply creating a new one.

When i create a new application and try to create a region on a page the attached always occurs. This also occurs if i create a new page in a current applications that were already in place before the Apex 4.2 upgrade. Was it even to do with the upgrade?

I assume its something in the Templates or Themes under Shared Componants but i cannot see anything that sticks out.

I thought i would try an HTML5 template to see if that made any difference however the same occurs, see screenprint.

[image]

Is there an answer why this is happening and how it could be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really looks like it is a template "issue". You need to check your page template: what is it named?

For example, in Theme 23 there are several page templates which include a left, right or both sidebars. When your page uses a template with this sidebar, then the sidebar will always use up a portion of the screen.
If you have no template specified but rather use the "Application Default", then go to "Shared Components > Templates" and look at the page templates section for the template which has a check in the "Default" column. Most likely it is a template including a sidebar.

Aside from that you could also always use a tool to inspect the HTML and CSS. For example, with Firebug in Firefox you could rightclick on the empty space left of your region and choose "inspect element with firebug". It might be a TD element. It might be a div with a fixed width. It might be custom css pushing things about.

Comment: The funny thing is, i create a new page, its incorrect because the page is set to: 'One Level Tabs - Left Sidebar', so i change it just to 1 level tabs and it makes no difference to the page layout.

Comment: Did you check the page template itself under "shared components > templates"? It could very well be that there still is something there which causes it. Check in the body: is there a table structure? Are it just divs? If just divs, run the page and inspect the structure. For example, in firebug you'd be in the html tab. Make sure the correct element is selected, and then check the CSS tab in the right panel: maybe there is a fixed width? It is a bit hard to check this without anything tangible of course, and i can only take guesses. If you'd have an example on apex.oracle.com i could check it.